# Reset Password Doesn't Save New Password CakePHP 2.0

Tags: php, cakephp, forgot-password, reset-password

I have now got the system going through the process however for some reason, the code for actually updating the password in the database isn't updating anything? After insert new password and re-password, system immediately redirect to the login page, Even though no errors are shown?  Any thoughts? thanks.

This is my Reset Function

```
function reset($token=null){
    $this->User->recursive=-1;
    if(!empty($token)){
        $u=$this->User->findBytokenhash($token);
        if($u){
            $this->User->id=$u['User']['id'];
            if($this->request->is('post')){
                $this->User->data=$this->request->data;
                $this->User->data['User']['username']=$u['User']['username'];
                $new_hash=sha1($u['User']['username'].rand(0,100));//created token
                $this->User->data['User']['tokenhash']=$new_hash;
                // print_r($this->request->data);
                //      exit;
                if($this->User->validates(array('fieldList'=>array('password','password_confirm')))){
                    if($this->User->save($this->User->data)){
                        $this->Session->setFlash('Password Has been Updated');
                        $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'login'));
                    }
                } else{
                    $this->set('errors',$this->User->invalidFields());
                }
            }
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Token Corrupted,,Please Retry.the reset link work only for once.');
        }
    } else{
        $this->redirect('/');
    }
}
```

And this is my reset.ctp

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User', array('action' => 'reset')); ?>
<?php
    if(isset($errors)){
        echo '<div class="error">';
        echo "<ul>";
        foreach($errors as $error){
            echo "<li><div class='error-message'>$error</div></li>";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
        echo '</div>';
    }
?>
<form method="post">
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('User.password', array('type' => 'password',
                                                       'name' => '$data[User][password]',
                                                       'class' => 'form-control'));
        echo $this->Form->input('User.re_password', array('type' => 'password',
                                                        'name' => 'data[User][re_password]',
                                                        'class' => 'form-control'));
    ?>
    <input type="submit" class="button" style="float:left;margin-left:3px;" value="Save" />
    <?php echo $this->Form->end();?>
</form>
```

Please, help me , thanks

Comment: on ctp file in form tag you does not send token again just remove action from form tag in your ctp and then check

Comment: @BharatMaheshwari yes i'm using Auth too

Comment: also I saw two form tag opened and one one is closed, remove the second one

Answer (score 0):

Replace your ctp code by this

```
 <?php echo $this->Form->create('User'); ?>
<?php
if(isset($errors)){
    echo '<div class="error">';
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach($errors as $error){
        echo "<li><div class='error-message'>$error</div></li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('User.password', array('type' => 'password',
                                                   'name' => '$data[User][password]',
                                                   'class' => 'form-control'));
    echo $this->Form->input('User.re_password', array('type' => 'password',
                                                    'name' => 'data[User][re_password]',
                                                    'class' => 'form-control'));
?>
<input type="submit" class="button" style="float:left;margin-left:3px;" value="Save" />
<?php echo $this->Form->end();?>
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: check what is in your $this->data. Is it getting $token or not?

Comment: i get the value of token, but the problem is when submit new password, password not save into database, in database still past password @bharat

Comment: did you check in db for new row inserted besides updating the old one? It might be possible that you does not have a primary field named "id" in $this->data so it inserts a new row every time

Comment: i was check my database, i have primary field 'id' and i was check too my database not insert row automatic when updating the old one

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed ,

You shuld use `$this->User->save($this->request->data)`

Check out using this

```
    echo $this->Form->input('User.password', array('type' => 'password',
                                                   'class' => 'form-control'));
    echo $this->Form->input('User.re_password', array('type' => 'password',
                                                    'class' => 'form-control'));
```

Let name attribute built by cakephp to match with database table,fields. I think you have only one or 2 ctp etc, you are just building your project from start , correct?

Comment: @dery , i dont have access to your project , and i am trying to help you, you said i m so frustrated ??

Comment: Being frustrated wont work if you want to debug code . Check if you have any beforeSave() method in User Model?

Comment: hey , can i have your email ? i'll send my project, i build this project for learning, haha yaa frustrated why this problem not solved

Comment: public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
  if (!empty($this->data['User']['re_password'])) {
    $this->data['User']['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data['User']['re_password']);

    unset($this->data['User']['re_password']);
  }
}

Comment: thats my beforeSave User Model

Comment: @dery , ok , nutandevjoshi@gmail.com . And one more If you see problem is complex, while debugging , split the problem into modules, then use debug (print_r)   , in each , this is how debugging is done.

Comment: oke thanks a lot bro, sorry because i'm still learning and newbie as programmer, then i'll send this project to you @jquery

Comment: @dery , i will need Database too

Comment: Last try use `public function beforeSave($options = array()) 
{ 
 if (!empty($this->data['User']['re_password'])) 
 { 
  $this->data['User']['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data['User']['re_password']); unset($this->data['User']['re_password']); 
 } 
    return true;
} 
`  If doesnt work , i wil see your project.

Comment: check return true added at the end

Comment: ,Did you already find a solution for me to solved this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
public function beforeSave() {
    if (isset($this->data['User']['password'])) { 
        $this->data['User']['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data['User']['password']);
    }
    return true;
}
```

and in function reset

```
if($this->User->save($this->User->data,false))
```

it worked for me. Hope it works for you!!